# source conda environment to export QHOME, can't execute q command

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, kdb

I am trying to install kdb on the jupyter-notebook. First I download the 64-bit windows version on https://ondemand.kx.com/ and also download the licence in the email.

Then I open it using window command prompt. I set QHOME and PATH using the following code in command prompt:

```
setx QHOME "C:\q"
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\q\w64"
exit
```

I can run q properly in windows command.

However, when I open Anaconda3 prompt, to run the q, by typing:

```
activate base
q
```

The error appears

```
python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Cecil': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My directory path in Anaconda is

```
(base) C:\Users\Cecil M>
```

And when I open the jupyter-book, the kernel is dead

Is there any step missing here. I have downloaded relative packages, such as kx kdb, kx embedpy, kx jupyterq.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the space in your username.

The Anaconda KDB package is setting the variable `QHOME` to `C:\Users\Cecil M\Anaconda3\q`.

The script `etc\conda\activate.d\kdb_activate.bat` is run when anaconda starts and sets the `QHOME` variable. Adding quotes to this variable in the script might work, ie

```
@echo off
set OLD_QHOME=%QHOME%
set QHOME="%CONDA_PREFIX%\q"
```

If this fails, deleting the `kdb_activate.bat` script will stop `QHOME` from being reassigned when Anaconda is started and KDB should load as usual.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package available that handles this error. You can install it from anaconda and therefore you don't need to manually change anything. The name of the packages are kdb-3.6-2018.10.23. You upgrade using the command below.

`conda upgrade -c kx kdb`

Hope this helps.